# Is it bad if the train score is much higher thanthe test score?

Tags: overfitting

I'm doing a binary classification problem and using accuracy as my metric (I know that's not always advisable but, for now, it makes sense here). I trained a [random forest classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) with [grid search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) on the training set and then took the model with the best parameters and applied it to the test data.

The results I got are:

- Training data: accuracy is 93.28%
- Testing data: 82.44%

I know that this means that, on further unseen data, I should expect an accuracy of about 82.44% (under assumptions relating to the data coming from the same sample). My question is this: is it bad that the model is so over-fit? Is this something I should try to avoid? Or, if I'm happy with an 82% accuracy, can I just accept this?

Comment: It's not a big difference between the scores. Quite typical one, I'd say.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks @Tim! In general though, let's say my testing score is much less than my training score, but still good enough for what I'm doing, is that a big problem?

Comment: If your test data is typical of further unseen data, and you have only tested once, then "good enough" is as good as it gets